# A Django view is being called when I don't want it to be - why?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on the cs50 web development Network assignment. Essentially it is a barebones twitter copycat. I have an issue where a view from views.py is being called when I do not intend it to be called. I know below I am posting more than is needed of my code below, but I feel I need to since I don't know where the problem area is.

The views.py function follow_count() is being called eventually when I call the index view but cannot determine why. I.e. it is called every time the homepage is loaded. I do not want it to be called until it is specifically called by the clicked event listener in the js file. I cannot figure out what is causing follow_count() to run early, every time I load the index view. As I follow the path of different functions calling each other, it doesn't appear that anything is calling follow_count() yet it runs anyway.

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import User, Post, Profile


def index(request):

    print("index running in python")

    if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST["post-body"]
        new_post = Post()
        new_post.poster = request.user
        new_post.body = post

        new_post.save()

    return render(request, "network/index.html")

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "network/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "network/login.html")

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "network/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)

        #auto-create a profile for new user
        new_profile = Profile()
        new_profile.user = user
        new_profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "network/register.html")

def all_posts(request):

    print("all_posts running in python")
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts = posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()
    print(f"{posts}")

    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)

def follow_count(request, username_lookup):

    print(f"follow_count running in python")

    user = User.objects.get(username='dannl')
    profiles = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    print(username_lookup)

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username_lookup)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    try:
        profiles = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return JsonResponse([profiles.serialize()], safe=False)

def follow(request, username_lookup):

    print("follow runnning in python")

    followed_user = User.objects.get(username=username_lookup)
    print(f"followed_user is {followed_user.username}")

    followed_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=followed_user)

    following_user = request.user
    print("step 3 done")
    print(f"following_user is {following_user.username}")

    following_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=following_user)

    followed_profile.followers.add(following_user)
    following_profile.following.add(followed_user)

    return render(request, "network/index.html")

def unfollow(request, username_lookup):

    print("unfollow runnning in python")

    unfollowed_user = User.objects.get(username=username_lookup)
    print(f"unfollowed_user is {unfollowed_user.username}")

    unfollowed_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=unfollowed_user)

    unfollowing_user = request.user
    print("step 3 done")
    print(f"unfollowing_user is {unfollowing_user.username}")

    unfollowing_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=unfollowing_user)

    unfollowed_profile.followers.remove(unfollowing_user)
    unfollowing_profile.following.remove(unfollowed_user)

    return render(request, "network/index.html")

def follow_button(request, username_lookup):
    print("follow_button running in python")
    current_logged_user = request.user
    current_logged_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=current_logged_user)
    print(f"current_logged_profile is {current_logged_profile.user.username}")
    return JsonResponse([current_logged_profile.serialize()], safe=False)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("all_posts", views.all_posts, name="all_posts"),
    path("<str:username_lookup>", views.follow_count, name="follow_count"),
    path("<str:username_lookup>/follow", views.follow, name="follow"),
    path("<str:username_lookup>/unfollow", views.unfollow, name="unfollow"),
    path("<str:username_lookup>/follow_button", views.follow_button, name="follow_button"),
    path("profile_info", views.follow_button, name="profile_info")
]
```

index.html

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

        <div id="index-display"> 
            <h3>All Posts</h3>
            <br>
            <div id="new-post">
                <h5>New Post</h5>
                <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" placeholder="Type post here"></textarea>
                    <input id="post-message" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="all-posts">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="profile-display">
            <h3 id="profile-name"></h3>
            <br>
            <b>Followers: </b><b id="followers"></b>
            <b>Following: </b><b id="following"></b>
            <div id="profile-posts">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="following-display">
            <h3>Following</h3>
            <br>
            <div id="following-posts">
            </div>
        </div>


    {% else %}
        <strong> Login To See Posts</strong>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

index.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.querySelector('#following-link').addEventListener('click', () => {
        load_posts_following();
    });

    load_posts();
})

function load_posts() {

    console.log("load_posts running");

    document.querySelector('#index-display').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#profile-display').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#following-display').style.display = 'none';


    fetch('/all_posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
        // Print posts
        console.log(posts);
        posts.forEach(post => show_posts(post));
    });
}

function show_posts(post) {

    console.log("show_posts running")
    //create 'main' div (will add content to it below), and store it in a variable
    const post_display = document.createElement('div');
    post_display.id = 'post';
    post_display.className = 'col-lg-10 col-md-20 col-sm-30 border';
    
    console.log("step 1: div created")
    //create new element for link to profiles, add it to the 'main' div
    const post_poster = document.createElement('div');
    post_poster.id = 'post-poster';
    post_poster.innerHTML = post.poster;
    post_poster.addEventListener('click', event => {
        username_lookup = event.target.innerHTML;
        load_posts_profile(username_lookup);
    });
    post_display.append(post_poster);  

    console.log("step 2 done")
    //create new div to display post, add it to the 'main' div
    const post_body = document.createElement('div');
    post_body.id = 'post-body';
    post_body.innerHTML = post.body;
    post_display.append(post_body);

    console.log("step 3 done")
    //create new div to display timestamp, add it to the 'main' div
    const post_timestamp = document.createElement('div');
    post_timestamp.id = 'post-timestamp';
    post_timestamp.innerHTML = post.timestamp;
    post_display.append(post_timestamp);

    console.log("step 4 done")
    //create new div to display # of likes, add it to the 'main' div
    const post_likes = document.createElement('div');
    post_likes.id = 'post-likes';
    post_likes.innerHTML = `Likes: ${post.likes}`;
    post_display.append(post_likes);

    console.log("step 5 done");
    document.querySelector('#all-posts').append(post_display);

    console.log("post appended");
}

function load_posts_following() {

    console.log("load_posts_following running");

    document.querySelector('#index-display').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#profile-display').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#following-display').style.display = 'block';

    fetch('/profile_info')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(profiles_returned => {
        console.log(profiles_returned);
        profiles_returned.forEach(profile => {
    
            fetch('/all_posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(posts => {
                // Print posts
                console.log(posts);
                posts.forEach(post => show_posts_following(post, profile));
            });
        });
    });
}

function show_posts_following(post, profile) {
    
    console.log("show_posts_following running");
    console.log(post.poster);
    console.log(profile);
    console.log(profile.following_usernames);

    if (profile.following_usernames.includes(post.poster)) {
        
        //create 'main' div (will add content to it below), and store it in a variable
        const post_display = document.createElement('div');
        post_display.id = 'post';
        post_display.className = 'col-lg-10 col-md-20 col-sm-30 border';
        
        //create new element for link to profiles, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_poster = document.createElement('div');
        post_poster.id = 'post-poster';
        post_poster.innerHTML = post.poster;
        post_display.append(post_poster);

        //create new div to display post, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_body = document.createElement('div');
        post_body.id = 'post-body';
        post_body.innerHTML = post.body;
        post_display.append(post_body);

        //create new div to display timestamp, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_timestamp = document.createElement('div');
        post_timestamp.id = 'post-timestamp';
        post_timestamp.innerHTML = post.timestamp;
        post_display.append(post_timestamp);

        //create new div to display # of likes, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_likes = document.createElement('div');
        post_likes.id = 'post-likes';
        post_likes.innerHTML = `Likes: ${post.likes}`;
        post_display.append(post_likes);

        document.querySelector('#following-posts').append(post_display);
    }
}

function load_posts_profile(username_lookup) {

    console.log("load_posts_profile running");

    document.querySelector('#index-display').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#profile-display').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#following-display').style.display = 'none';

    document.querySelector('#profile-name').innerHTML = username_lookup;

    fetch(`/${username_lookup}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(profiles => {
        console.log(profiles);
        profiles.forEach(profile => show_follow_count(profile));
        follow_button(username_lookup, profiles);
    });
    

    fetch('/all_posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
        // Print posts
        console.log(posts);
        posts.forEach(post => show_posts_profile(post, username_lookup));
    });
}

function show_posts_profile(post, username_lookup) {
    
    console.log("show_posts_profile running");
    console.log(post.poster);

    if (post.poster === username_lookup) {
        
        //create 'main' div (will add content to it below), and store it in a variable
        const post_display = document.createElement('div');
        post_display.id = 'post';
        post_display.className = 'col-lg-10 col-md-20 col-sm-30 border';
        
        //create new element for link to profiles, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_poster = document.createElement('div');
        post_poster.id = 'post-poster';
        post_poster.innerHTML = post.poster;
        post_display.append(post_poster);

        //create new div to display post, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_body = document.createElement('div');
        post_body.id = 'post-body';
        post_body.innerHTML = post.body;
        post_display.append(post_body);

        //create new div to display timestamp, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_timestamp = document.createElement('div');
        post_timestamp.id = 'post-timestamp';
        post_timestamp.innerHTML = post.timestamp;
        post_display.append(post_timestamp);


        //create new div to display # of likes, add it to the 'main' div
        const post_likes = document.createElement('div');
        post_likes.id = 'post-likes';
        post_likes.innerHTML = `Likes: ${post.likes}`;
        post_display.append(post_likes);


        document.querySelector('#profile-posts').append(post_display);
    }
}

function show_follow_count(profile) {

    document.querySelector('#followers').innerHTML = `${profile.followers}`;
    document.querySelector('#following').innerHTML = `${profile.following}`;
}

function follow(username_lookup) {

    console.log("follow running")
    fetch(`/${username_lookup}/follow`)
    .then(response => null)
}

function unfollow(username_lookup) {

    console.log("unfollow running")
    fetch(`/${username_lookup}/unfollow`)
    .then(response => null)
}

function update_followers() {

   const before_followers = document.querySelector('#followers').innerHTML;
   console.log(before_followers);
   var after_followers = parseInt(before_followers) + 1;
   after_followers = parseInt(after_followers);
   console.log(after_followers);
   document.querySelector('#followers').innerHTML = `${after_followers}`;
}

function update_followers_unfollow() {

    const before_followers = document.querySelector('#followers').innerHTML;
    console.log(before_followers);
    var after_followers = parseInt(before_followers) - 1;
    after_followers = parseInt(after_followers);
    console.log(after_followers);
    document.querySelector('#followers').innerHTML = `${after_followers}`;
}

function follow_button(username_lookup) {

    console.log("follow_button running")

    fetch(`/${username_lookup}/follow_button`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(current_logged_profile => {
        console.log(current_logged_profile);
        current_logged_profile.forEach(profile => {
            if (username_lookup === profile.username) {
                console.log("own profile found - no follow button");
            }
            
            else if (profile.following_usernames.includes(username_lookup)) {

                console.log("unfollow button");
                const unfollow_button = document.createElement('button');    
                unfollow_button.innerHTML = "Unfollow";
                unfollow_button.style.width = '50px';
                unfollow_button.style.height = '25px';
                profile_header = document.querySelector('#profile-name');
                profile_header.append(unfollow_button);
                unfollow_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    unfollow(username_lookup);
                    update_followers_unfollow();
                })
            }

            else {
                console.log("not already follower - follow button");
                const follow_button = document.createElement('button');    
                follow_button.innerHTML = "Follow";
                follow_button.style.width = '50px';
                follow_button.style.height = '25px';
                profile_header = document.querySelector('#profile-name');
                profile_header.append(follow_button);
                follow_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    follow(username_lookup);
                    update_followers();
                });
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `profile_info` before the `<str:username>`, otherwise that will be the first *match*, and thus fire the follow_count`instead of the`follow_button`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('all_posts', views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
    #    ↓ first profile_info before <str:username_lookup>
    path('profile_info', views.follow_button, name='profile_info'),
    path('<str:username_lookup>', views.follow_count, name='follow_count'),
    path('<str:username_lookup>/follow', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('<str:username_lookup>/unfollow', views.unfollow, name='unfollow'),
    path('<str:username_lookup>/follow_button', views.follow_button, name='follow_button'),
]
```